# Execute photoshop actions with parameters from a data set

Tags: javascript, adobe, photoshop, photoshop-script

I am developing a photoshop automation application. I do not have a deep knowledge of photoshop and I was hoping someone can offer some advice. 
I am developing this applications for Adobe Photoshop Creative Suite 17 (CS 17).
 I am passing in data into my Photoshop script via a json file. 
 The json file contains a parameters for files that I am generating, pattern 
 name, color, scale etc...

I also have a set of commands ready that will perform tasks necessary to apply 
 patterns and colors and then save the file.

My question: **is it possible to pass in variables into the action with a JavaScript script?**

I know I can execute actions with a code snippet:

```
app.actions["actionName"].play()
```

but is it possible to pass in a parameter into the action? For example, I have an action that applies a given pattern or color, is it possible to pass a pattern name or color into the action from my data set?
if so how would I do that ? Please advise .

Comment: It *should* be possible, only I don't know how. What you might want in the mean time is to turn your action into a script and change a line or two into a variable. [action to javascript](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2073814) An ugly alternative would be to have a number of actions one for every pattern or colour and change that. Not a good solution though

Comment: ...Either that or [edit your action via xml](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/696989)